# MYSQL obtener datos agrupados en SELECT con IF

Tags: mysql

tengo el siguiente codigo SQL

```
SELECT e.sigla_equipo,
e.patente_equipo,
IF(j.nombre_jornada = 'NOCHE', CONCAT(c.nombre_conductor, ' ',c.apellidoPat_conductor), '') as noche,
IF(j.nombre_jornada = 'DIA', CONCAT(c.nombre_conductor, ' ',c.apellidoPat_conductor), '') as dia
FROM conductor c
INNER JOIN conductor_equipo ce ON ce.id_conductor = c.id_conductor
INNER JOIN equipo e ON e.id_equipo = ce.id_equipo
INNER JOIN jornada j ON j.id_jornada = ce.id_jornada
INNER JOIN estado_conductor ec ON ec.id_estado_conductor = c.id_estado_conductor 
INNER JOIN base b ON b.id_base = c.id_base
WHERE b.nombre_base = 'Base' AND ec.abrev_estado_conductor != 'DES'
```

que me permite obtener un camión, su patente y sus dos conductores pero en dos filas, de la siguiente manera:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo que quiero es que el resultado **se vea solo en una fila.** Probé con un GROUP BY por e.id_equipo, pero no aparece el conductor de noche.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La tabla conductor_equipo es:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Aplicando Group By queda así:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Podes mostrarnos los datos de tu tabla de origen? el problema viene por ese lado..

Comment: Gracias por la observación. Se adjunta la tabla donde convergen las llaves de las otras tablas.

Comment: Como hiciste el group by? porque la solucion es esa...

Comment: En la consulta añadí el Group By y solo muestra un turno, el de día =(

Comment: fijate en mi respuesta ;)

Comment: Recuerda que es dificil ver algunas imagenes, sobre todo las del codigo. Tu codigo siempre debe ir como texto en la pregunta

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu `group by` es la solucion al problema.

Como lograste ya obtener los datos que querias, en distintos registros pero con las mismas "claves", lo unico que tenes que hacer es pasar eso a un nuevo query, que haga el `group by`.

Supongamos que llamamos a tu query actual A.

Entonces, podrias hacer lo siguiene:

```
Select 
  A.sigla_equipo,
  A.patente_equipo,
  max(A.noche),
  max(A.dia)
from (SELECT e.sigla_equipo,
        e.patente_equipo,
        IF(j.nombre_jornada = 'NOCHE', CONCAT(c.nombre_conductor, ' ',c.apellidoPat_conductor), '') as noche,
        IF(j.nombre_jornada = 'DIA', CONCAT(c.nombre_conductor, ' ',c.apellidoPat_conductor), '') as dia
        FROM conductor c
        INNER JOIN conductor_equipo ce ON ce.id_conductor = c.id_conductor
        INNER JOIN equipo e ON e.id_equipo = ce.id_equipo
        INNER JOIN jornada j ON j.id_jornada = ce.id_jornada
        INNER JOIN estado_conductor ec ON ec.id_estado_conductor = c.id_estado_conductor 
        INNER JOIN base b ON b.id_base = c.id_base
        WHERE b.nombre_base = 'Base' AND ec.abrev_estado_conductor != 'DES') A
group by A.sigla_equipo, A.patente_equipo
```

Estoy usando tu consulta, como ingreso a mi consulta. Eso quiere decir, que el from de mi consulta no es una tabla, si no que es el resultado de tu consultado.

Por eso, hay un from, que contiene toda tu consulta, y a eso lo llamo A, y eso es lo que toma para hacer el group by.

Comment: El resultado es el mismo =(

Comment: vos estas seguro que lo estas escribiendo bien? mira http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/4a8d2f/3

Comment: Por algún extraño motivo no me aparece el turno de noche con el group by, sin este, si aparece. Probé cambiando en los IF del SELECT el nombre_jornada por id_jornada con el mismo resultado.

Comment: Si tu select devuelve lo que vos decis, tu group by escrito como lo puse yo, que es un poco diferente al que tenes vos, debe devolver lo que vos queres.

Comment: observa bien .. hizo una subconsulta general y en la consulta principal hizo un group by

Comment: Exactamente. no vi bien ese group by y lo dejé dentro de la subconsulta. Ahora me muestra lo que deseo. Gracias señores, esto fue un dolor de cabeza.

Answer (score 2):

Vas en la línea correcta con la idea de agrupar. Lo que debes hacer es, para las columnas `dia` y `noche` aplicar alguna función de agregación, como `min()` o `max()`. Dado que en la fila de *día* la columna `noche` está vacía, y viceversa, debiera funcionar bien con ambas.

La solución sería, por ejemplo:

```
SELECT   e.sigla_equipo
       , e.patente_equipo
       , max(IF(j.nombre_jornada = 'NOCHE', CONCAT(c.nombre_conductor, ' ',c.apellidoPat_conductor), '')) as noche
       , max(IF(j.nombre_jornada = 'DIA', CONCAT(c.nombre_conductor, ' ',c.apellidoPat_conductor), '')) as dia
  FROM conductor c
       INNER JOIN conductor_equipo ce ON ce.id_conductor = c.id_conductor
       INNER JOIN equipo e ON e.id_equipo = ce.id_equipo
       INNER JOIN jornada j ON j.id_jornada = ce.id_jornada
       INNER JOIN estado_conductor ec ON ec.id_estado_conductor = c.id_estado_conductor 
       INNER JOIN base b ON b.id_base = c.id_base
 WHERE b.nombre_base = 'Base' 
   AND ec.abrev_estado_conductor != 'DES'
 GROUP BY e.sigla_equipo
       , e.patente_equipo
```

Comment: Gracias amigo. De la forma que lo describes también funciona correctamente. Me faltaban las funciones de agregación por lo visto, lo desconocía totalmente.